# How to create an empty collection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am experimenting with using Clojure for modelling a certain set of data which are

- not well defined (I am figuring out the optimal structures for those data while working with them) and
- gradually being refined (when I first declare a certain object I know very little about it, as I am working on this project, I get to know more and more about it and want to capture it in Clojure).

At the very start, I want that complex piece of data be just an empty collection. At this point I don't care whether it's a list, a set, or a vector.

```
(ns clojure-playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(def my-complex-object (hash-set))
```

When I compile this file and enter `(my-complex-object)` in REPL, I get an error.

Same with

- `(def my-complex-object ())`,
- `(def my-complex-object [])`,
- `(def my-complex-object (list))`, and
- `(def my-complex-object '(list))`.

**How can I bind `my-complex-object` to an empty collection?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get error, because this expression `(my-complex-object)` calls *function* named my-complex-object. Use any from these definitions:

```
(def my-complex-object #{})
(def my-complex-object (hash-set))
(def my-complex-object ())
(def my-complex-object (list))
(def my-complex-object [])
(def my-complex-object (vector))
```

and then just evaluate `my-complex-object` (without parentheses).
If you do both in REPL, it will look like this:

```
(def my-complex-object [])
=> #'clojure-playground.core/my-complex-object
my-complex-object
=> []
```

Note that each collection type has different behaviour for operations like `conj`, `pop` or handling duplicates.